# Left align in inline node

Tags: html, css

So I've got a row of text with a leading icon.  I need the text to multi-line align left while the icon remains centered vertically with relation to the text.

```
<div>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span>My block of long text that will go multiline when the window is resized</span>
</div>
```

Let me attempt to explain with some ASCII. I put a border on the row to help visualize it. 'O' is the icon.

```
+--------------------------------+
|     My block of long text that |
|  O  will go multiline when the |
|     window is resized          |
+--------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  O  My block of long text that will go multiline when the window is resized |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Unfortunately, my company's stuck (for the time being) using a home-brewed web framework that limits my use of javascript.  The goal here is to have this working with straight CSS, which I have full access to.  I've messed with floats, clears, inline, inline-block, block, margins, etc.  My front-end-fu is quite weak, so I need some help from some of you ninjas out there.

The overall point here is to make this look nice when the window is wide on desktop and when it's narrow on mobile.

TIA!

Comment: Do you have any relevant code you could add?

Comment: Are you able to set the height of the div that contains the icon and paragraph? Also, you're basically just going to set the icon to be  a box at a certain size so the paragraph knows never to go into that space.

Comment: Not that I can think of.  Perhaps just making it clear the div will be growing and shrinking.  Anything in particular you'd like to know about the context?

Comment: @slime I can set the height on both.  I can also set the width on the icon, but don't want to on the paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would involve positioning of the icon relative to the div with vertical alignment.

```css
div {
    background: #EEE;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 28px;
    min-height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698572-icon-6-mail-envelope-closed-24.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span>My block of long text that will go multiline when the window is resized</span>
</div>

<div style="width: 250px;">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span>My block of long text that will go multiline when the window is resized</span>
</div>

<div style="width: 200px;">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span>My block of long text that will go multiline when the window is resized</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be one solution:

```
.icon {
  width: 25px;
}

.otherspan {
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

This way your icon will always take up a fixed width and the text span will shrink as the viewport shrinks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it...

**HTML**

```
<div><span class="icon"></span><p>My block of long text that will go multiline when the window is resizedMy block of long text that will go multiline when the window is resizedMy block of long text that will go multiline when the window is resizedMy block of long text that will go multiline when the window is resized</p></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;}

div {
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 25px;}

.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;}

p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    padding-left: 25px;}
```

Comment: This works, but I've already chosen the other one.  I'll upvote as consolation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly though, this is what you are trying to do? 
Where the `<div class="image"></div>` is your image

```css
.image {
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="image"></div>
            </td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porttitor rhoncus porta. Phasellus porttitor magna sed diam ullamcorper tincidunt. Maecenas tempor molestie iaculis. Fusce ultricies elit et commodo faucibus. Quisque vel velit id urna tincidunt pharetra. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc in est nec magna pulvinar pellentesque. Donec ac dui lacinia, blandit nulla vel, eleifend mi. Integer non tellus at massa ornare feugiat id a enim. Suspendisse vel placerat orci. Morbi vitae nulla sed augue tristique sollicitudin sed ut lacus. Mauris vulputate placerat tincidunt. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus ultrices in nulla blandit molestie. Praesent vel nisl rutrum, maximus mauris egestas, consequat enim. Nulla eget dapibus arcu.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ahh yes, tables.  I would have gone with this, but @dfsq's solution worked without them.  Thanks for the answer.